# Inconsistency between 'read.csv' and 'write.csv' in R

Tags: r

The R function `read.csv` works as the following as stated in the manual: "If there is a header and the first row contains one fewer field than the number of columns, the first column in the input is used for the row names." That's good. However, when it comes to the function `write.csv`, I cannot find a way to write the csv file in a similar way. So, if I have a `file.txt` as below:

```
Column_1,Column_2
Row_1,2,3
Row_2,4,5
```

Then when I read it using `a = read.csv('file.txt')`, the row and column names are `Row_x` and `Column_x` as expected. However, when I write the matrix `a` to a csv file again, then what I get as a result from `write.csv('file2.txt', quote=F)` is as below:

```
,Column_1,Column_2
Row_1,2,3
Row_2,4,5
```

So, there is a comma in the beginning of this file. And if I would read this file again using `a2 = read.csv('file2.txt')`, then resulting `a2` will not be the same as the previous matrix `a`. The row names of the matrix `a2` will not be `Row_x`. That's, I do not want a comma in the beginning of the file. How can I get rid of this comma while using `write.csv`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two functions that you have mentioned, read.cvs and write.csv are just a specific form of the more generic functions read.table and write.table.

When I copy your example data into a .csv and try to read it with read.csv, R throws a warning and says that the header line was incomplete.  Thus it resorted to special behaviour to fix the error.  Because we had an incomplete file, it completed the file by adding an empty element at the top left.  R understands that this is a header row, and thus the data appears okay in R, but when we write to a csv, it doesn't understand what is header and what is not.  Thus the empty element only appearing in the header row created by R shows up as a regular element.  Which you would expect. Basically it made our table into a 3x3 because it can't have a weird number of elements.

You want the extra comma there, because it allows programs to read the column names in the right place.  In order to read the file in again you can do the following, assuming test.csv is your data.  You can fix this by manually adding the column and row names in R, including the missing element to put everything in place.

To fix the wonky row names, you're going to want to add an extra option specifying which row is the row names (row.names = your_column_number) when you read it back in with the comma correctly in place.

```
y <- read.csv(file = "foo.csv") #this throws a warning because your input is incorrect
write.csv(y, "foo_out.csv")
x <- read.csv(file = "foo.csv", header = T, row.names = 1) #this will read the first column as the row names.
```

Play around with read/write.csv, but it might be worth while to move into the more generic functions read.table and write.table.  They offer expanded functionality.

To read a csv in the generic function

```
y <- read.table(file = "foo.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

thus you can specify the delimiter and easily read in excel spreadsheets (separated by tab or "\t") or space delimited files   ( " " ).

Hope that helps.

Comment: You can also write a table w/o the row names using `write.csv(..., row.names=FALSE)`.

Comment: Actually, the solution is adding `row.names=1` parameter to `read.csv`. Both `file.txt` and `file2.txt` can then be read well and the results will be the same. So, `a = read.csv('file.txt', row.names=1)` and `write.csv(a, 'file2.txt')` calls are consistent with each other. When you call `read.csv` once more using `a2 = read.csv('file2.txt', row.names=1)`, then the variables `a` and `a2` will be exactly the same.